# hibernate doesn't link entities if I close session

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have many to many association between Student and Prepod.

my mapping

Prepod:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "prepod")
public class Prepod {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long i) {
        id = i;
    }[/code]
```

Student:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long age;
    private List<Prepod> prepods = new ArrayList<Prepod>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Prepod> getPrepods() {
        return prepods;
    }

    public void setPrepods(List<Prepod> prepods) {
        this.prepods = prepods;
    }

    public Student() {
        name = null;
    }

    public Student(Student s) {
        name = s.getName();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Column(name = "age")
    public Long getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setId(Long i) {
        id = i;
    }

    public void setName(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public void setAge(Long age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I have two variant invocation code, that use my model.

first variant:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Prepod prepod = (Prepod) session.get(Prepod.class, 1l);
        Student student = (Student) session.get(Student.class, 1l);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add(student);

        List<Prepod> prepods = new ArrayList<Prepod>();
        prepods.add(prepod);

        prepod.setStudents(students);
        student.setPrepods(prepods);

        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(student);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

appropriate hibernate log:

```
Hibernate: select prepod0_.id as id1_1_1_, prepod0_.name as name2_1_1_, students1_.prepods_id as prepods1_1_3_, student2_.id as students2_2_3_, student2_.id as id1_0_0_, student2_.age as age2_0_0_, student2_.name as name3_0_0_ from prepod prepod0_ left outer join prepod_Student students1_ on prepod0_.id=students1_.prepods_id left outer join Student student2_ on students1_.students_id=student2_.id where prepod0_.id=?
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_0_1_, student0_.age as age2_0_1_, student0_.name as name3_0_1_, prepods1_.students_id as students2_0_3_, prepod2_.id as prepods1_2_3_, prepod2_.id as id1_1_0_, prepod2_.name as name2_1_0_ from Student student0_ left outer join prepod_Student prepods1_ on student0_.id=prepods1_.students_id left outer join prepod prepod2_ on prepods1_.prepods_id=prepod2_.id where student0_.id=?
Hibernate: update Student set age=?, name=? where id=?
```

This log shows that hibernate update only student entity. link with prepod doesn't updates.

And I write second variant code invocation without session close:

```
 Prepod prepod = (Prepod) session.get(Prepod.class, 1l);
    Student student = (Student) session.get(Student.class, 1l);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.flush();
//  session.close(); // first change
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    students.add(student);

    List<Prepod> prepods = new ArrayList<Prepod>();
    prepods.add(prepod);

    prepod.setStudents(students);
    student.setPrepods(prepods);

   // session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();//second change
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(student);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

Appropriate hibernate log:

```
Hibernate: select prepod0_.id as id1_1_1_, prepod0_.name as name2_1_1_, students1_.prepods_id as prepods1_1_3_, student2_.id as students2_2_3_, student2_.id as id1_0_0_, student2_.age as age2_0_0_, student2_.name as name3_0_0_ from prepod prepod0_ left outer join prepod_Student students1_ on prepod0_.id=students1_.prepods_id left outer join Student student2_ on students1_.students_id=student2_.id where prepod0_.id=?
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_0_1_, student0_.age as age2_0_1_, student0_.name as name3_0_1_, prepods1_.students_id as students2_0_3_, prepod2_.id as prepods1_2_3_, prepod2_.id as id1_1_0_, prepod2_.name as name2_1_0_ from Student student0_ left outer join prepod_Student prepods1_ on student0_.id=prepods1_.students_id left outer join prepod prepod2_ on prepods1_.prepods_id=prepod2_.id where student0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into prepod_Student (prepods_id, students_id) values (?, ?)
```

This log shows that at this variant hibernate update link between these entities.

Can you explain principical deffierencies between my examples for me?

Answer (score 0):

Changes made to a persistent entity that is in the managed state become persistent.  This is the entire point of JPA/Hibernate.  If the entity is in the managed state (was loaded by a currently open session and not detached), changes will persist next time that session flushes.  If you haven't explicitly started a transaction hibernate will just do it in auto-commit mode.  Updating entities has conceptually nothing to do with database transaction boundaries.  Those are an implementation detail of the persistence mechanism that tends to leak through the abstraction.

Comment: and if I get prepod from first session and student from second how can I commit link between these?

Comment: You would have to attach the object to the session you're working in first. (Or turn on cascade)

Comment: can you post these variants?

Answer (score 0):

when you closing session, your object becomes **detached**. 
read this for more information http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html